# RethinkDB listen for changes on filter query?

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-javascript

I'm not sure if I fully understand the changefeeds correct... What I need to do is filter data based on current date like this:

```
r.table("messages")
  .filter(
    r.row("start").lt(r.now().toISO8601())
      .and(r.row("end").gt(r.now().toISO8601()))
  )
  .changes()
  .run(conn, (err, cursor) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }

    cursor.each(function (err, row) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      }

     // do stuff here

    });
  });
```

});

Is it even possible to do something like this? Or will .changes() only work if a field of a row is updated?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible and syntax is right.

However, just a note in case you miss it. The `r.now()` evaluated to the first time you ever run query, not the current time when changes happens.
r.now() is calculated only one time in same query and the return value is re-use on sub sequent calls: https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/javascript/now/

Changefeeds works with both of insert and updating. If the insert/updated document match the condition of your `filter`, it will be return in cursor. If it's an insert, `old_val` is `null`, if it's an update, old_val is old value.

Comment: Hm, okay.. so I would have to run this filter in a periodic loop, right and this should be no problem for rethink to run every second or so?

Comment: That seems a wrong approach I think. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe we can find another way for solution

Comment: -thx for your answers. I will try to explain what I'm trying to achieve: Messages have a start and endtime property which reflects the timeframe where this message should be displayed (a message will be send to a consumer when the timepoint has arrived to display it).  So... I need something that gets all messages at the current timepoint (periodically) which match "timepoint between starttime and endtime". Messages can come in at any point and must also be deleted when the endtime is reached... Dunno if this is really doable with Rethink though